# Symfony Routing not making sense

Tags: php, symfony

I'm teaching myself Symfony. And the routing doesn't make any sense.

I have a `postController` class with a few actions. Originally the crud generator from the command line gave me this;

```
/**
 * Post controller.
 *
 * @Route("/post")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Post entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="post_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //
    }

    //
}
```

What I want to achieve is to remove the `@Route` from the class itself. Thus I want my `indexAction` to be the the homepage, and all other actions in my class to still start with `/post`. For example, this is what I want;

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Post entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("post/{id}", name="post_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    // what I want for the showAction should count for all other Actions as well
}
```

When I make the change I get an error;

> No route found for "GET /post/"

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this. I don't think it is something major, it's probably something small that I just don't see. I want to make that `indexAction` my main action, the action when the website opens after a user logged in. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your route specification requires `{id}` parameter which is obligatory so there's no `"GET /post/"` route indeed. You need to do one of the following

1. Pass `id` value and access `/post/1` for example
2. Remove `{id}` from route specification and then you can access `/post/`
3. Pass default value for `id` so you can access both `/post/` and `/post/1`. To do that your route specification should look like `@Route("post/{id}", name="post_show", defaults={"id" = 1})`

Comment: It was not that route nor action's problem. I am aware of that one, I just made something quick here for the idea to show you. But yeah, I know, that can lead to unclear understandings (will still fix it in the question). It was more about the `indexAction()`. For some reason it works now, I think I forgot to try cache clearing...

Answer (score 0):

No route found for `"/post/"` is correct

because there is no route `"/post/"`
in your example theres only `"/"` and `"/post/{id}"`

so it makes perfect sense, i prefer to use the yml notation and prefixes so its not bound to a class

check the "YAML" tabs in the [DOCS](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/routing.html)

Comment: I know there is no route `"/post/"` but why does Symfony say there is one? But nevermind, for some reason it works now. I've continued with something else and cleared the cache for that and later I see that the routing works correct as well, so I guess it was the cache that had to be cleared. I thought I did try that....